# Windows java environment variables issue

Tags: javascript, java, windows, minecraft

After I set my java environment variables in Windows 10. It works at the first time, but after rebooting, when I executed the batch file, it would show that java command wasn't working.
Has anyone know what is going on? Below are my system variables, there's nothing in user variables

> JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5
> Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

When I go back to the setting page of environment variables, without any changes, after pressing apply, it suddenly works when opening the same batch file. I gotta do this process every time I reboot...

Comment: `there's nothing in user variables` - there should be, perhaps you're looking in the wrong place, since there's no "Apply" anywhere when dealing with system environment variables

Comment: In this particular case, since a gui is involved, it would be a good idea to post screenshots of what you've done

Comment: Sure, there you go, but my system is in Chinese lol...
https://postimg.cc/gallery/Xqrkrc2

Answer (score 0):

try this instead Path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin

Comment: Btw, I also has another path, which is PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\scripts
Will this make any difference, this is for the change of my java version